# XSLT version 1 URL encoding

Tags: xslt, urlencode

Is there a URL encoding function in XSLT version 1?
I need something similar to encodeURIComponent function in javascript?

Seeing as this is not possible as I'm using .NET platform as the XSLT is applied to a Sharepoint page. Is there a way to code this buy calling the javascript encode function within the XML, snippet below:

```
<xsl:template name="BuildLink">
    <xsl:param name="PrimarySubject" />
    <xsl:text>?PrimarySubject=</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$PrimarySubject" />
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use JScript embedded in XSLT ...

```
<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="custom">
function uriencode(string) {
 return encodeURIComponent(string);
}
</msxsl:script>
```

and call it like `custom:uriencode( url_to_encode )`

You will first need to define the namespace though by adding to the `<xsl:stylesheet ...` tag the 
`xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:custom="http://youdomain.ext/custom"`

***[update]***

the Url i put for the custom namespace could be anything .. [it is just a unique identifier](https://web.archive.org/web/20110313233545/http://www.loc.gov/standards/uri/xml-namespaces.html)..
(*the link concludes that it is less confusing if you do not use a url as the identifier..*)

***[udpdate 2]***

Some added info.
If you use MSXML6 then you need to manually allow scripting in the XSLT, by using the `AllowXsltScript` property.. ( [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754621(VS.85).aspx) )
Depending on the way you load the xslt and its settings have a look at the examples at [Script Blocks Using msxsl:script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/script-blocks-using-msxsl-script)  on how to alow scripts

Comment: calling as 
    <xsl:value-of select="custom:uriencode($PrimarySubject)" /> 
causes an error is this not the right way to call it?

Comment: try calling it with `<xsl:value-of select="custom:uriencode(string($PrimarySubject))" />`

Comment: what is the error returned ? ( *you have added the namespace right ?* )

Comment: yes - thanks, added the namespace, unfortunatley the error is not displayed as its doing the transform on sharepoint page... I am making the changes in ms sharepoint designer to the xslt and viewing on the sharepoint page.

Comment: i added a 2nd update in regard to MSXML6 not allowing by default the use of scripting inside XSLT..

Comment: In case anybody comes here and wonders: to allow scripting while using XslCompiledTransform.Trasform in c# .Net, you have to use this code: `XsltSettings xslt_settings = new XsltSettings();
                        xslt_settings.EnableScript = true;
                        XslCompiledTransform objXSLTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
                        objXSLTransform.Load(strXSLTFile, xslt_settings, new XmlUrlResolver());`

Answer (score 8):

These [XSLT 1.0 stylesheets](http://skew.org/xml/stylesheets/url-encode/) can be used to perform URL encode/decode:

1. [url-decode.xsl](http://skew.org/xml/stylesheets/url-encode/url-decode.xsl)
2. [url-encode.xsl](http://skew.org/xml/stylesheets/url-encode/url-encode.xsl)

> Description: Only a very small subset
>   of ASCII characters can be safely
>   embedded in a URI. Characters outside
>   this set must be escaped using
>   so-called "URL encoding" or
>   "%-escaping". The characters are
>   converted to bytes according to some
>   encoding (ASCII if possible) and those
>   bytes are each written as a '%'
>   followed by 2 hexadecimal digits. The
>   encoding used as the basis for this
>   conversion can be anything, but tends
>   to be dictated by the context in which
>   the URI is being used. Recent and
>   future standards use UTF-8, but legacy
>   applications including many
>   widely-deployed, server-side
>   processors of HTML form data assume
>   ISO-8859-1.
>
> For example, the greeting "¡Hola,
>   César!" can be embedded in a URI if it
>   is written as follows:
>   %A1Hola%2C%20C%E9sar!. (...assuming
>   ISO-8859-1 as the basis for encoding.
>   If it were UTF-8 based, then it would
>   be %C2%A1Hola%2C%20C%C3%A9sar!).
>
> The url-encode.xsl demo URL-encodes an
>   arbitrary string passed in as a
>   parameter named iso-string. It assumes
>   ISO-8859-1 will be the basis for the
>   URL-encoding. It should be compatible
>   with any XSLT 1.0 processor.
>
> Decoding an ISO-8859-1 based
>   URL-encoded string uses a similar
>   technique. See url-decode.xsl for a
>   demo. Its url parameter is the string
>   to be decoded.

Comment: Unfortunaltely this is not an universal solution as those stylesheets are limited to Latin1 and don't translate the whole Unicode charset.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one. XSLT has no knowledge of URLs and HTML.

Depending on the language and platform you are using, you may be able to use a [XSLT extension](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/09/05/extensions.html) that does that.

Answer (score 1):

You can, under certain circumstances use EXSLT (parser-provided extensions): [Dave Pawson's XSLT FAQ](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N3353.html#d4567e157) on this one.

However, XSLT is Turing complete, so you could write a basic URL encoder in XSLT itself, theoretically (I wouldn't try).