# XSLT stops output at blank in select

Tags: xslt

First I have to state that I touched XSLT today for the first time because a friend asked me for help.

We're trying to generate a link for GMaps. Everything works as long as there is no space in the variable we're using. Here's the code.

```
<xslt:template name="buildmaps">
    <xslt:param name="linkstart"/>
    <xslt:param name="link_target_street"/>
    <xslt:param name="link_target_postalcode"/>
    <xslt:param name="link_target_city"/>
    <xslt:param name="linktext"/>
    <xslt:param name="target"/>
        <xslt:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;a href=http://maps.google.de/maps?hl=de&amp;saddr=Hauptstr.%2057%2044789%20Bochum</xslt:text>
        <xslt:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;daddr=</xslt:text>
        <xslt:value-of select="$link_target_street"/>
        <xslt:text disable-output-escaping="yes">%20</xslt:text>
        <xslt:value-of select="$link_target_postalcode"/>
        <xslt:text disable-output-escaping="yes">%20</xslt:text>
        <xslt:value-of select="$link_target_city"/>         
        <xslt:text disable-output-escaping="yes">" target="</xslt:text>
        <xslt:value-of select="$target"/>
        <xslt:text disable-output-escaping="yes">"&gt;</xslt:text>
        <xslt:value-of select="$linktext"/>
        <xslt:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/a&gt;</xslt:text>
</xslt:template>
```

The problem occurs with the $link_target_street variable. Which looks like "Bahnhofstr. 9". We get our link allright like "http://maps.google.de/...daddr=Hauptstr.". So everything stops at the blank between Hauptstr. and 9.

Is there something I can do about it?

Thx in advance.

**Update:**

Now I know I'm using XSLT 1.0. So no replace for me :(

Now a bit about the output:

It should look like this:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.de/maps?hl=de&amp;saddr=Hauptstr.%2057%2044789%20Bochum&amp;daddr=Mainstreet%2023%2012345%20Bochum" target="_blank">
```

The problem lies in the street name. There I get:

```
... &amp;daddr=Mainstreet 23%2012345%20Bochum" ...
```

but I need

```
... &amp;daddr=Mainstreet%2023%2012345%20Bochum" ...
```

At this point I'm not sure if XSLT really stops at this blank or if the Url is just too broken to get handled properly. Either way if I could change the blank to '%20' everything would be fine. I think probably the links from Tomalak will help me out.

Unfortunately I'm at home now and have to set up a test environment myself but we found the debug option so I hope that will fasten the process.

Comment: What's the matter with all this `this disable-output-escaping="yes"` business?

Comment: Just found out about replace and tried:<xslt:value-of select="replace($link_target_street, ' ', '%20')"/> but it won't work either. Don't know about the disable-output-escaping stuff. We just copied prewritten stuff and tried to change it.

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you want to use? `replace` is XPath/XSLT 2.0 so don't expect that to work with XSLT 1.0 processors. And I agree with Tomalak, that code is awful, if you want to create an element with attributes then simply do e.g. `<a href="http://maps.google.de/maps?hl=de&amp;saddr=Hauptstr.%2057%2044789%20Bochum&amp;daddr={$link_target_street}" target="{$target}"><xsl:value-of select="$linktext"/></a>`.

Comment: Can you add sample input and desired output to your question?  It's a little difficult to decipher the goal from this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are shooting yourself in the foot.

```
<xslt:template name="buildmaps">
    <xslt:param name="linkstart"/>
    <xslt:param name="link_target_street"/>
    <xslt:param name="link_target_postalcode"/>
    <xslt:param name="link_target_city"/>
    <xslt:param name="linktext"/>
    <xslt:param name="target"/>
    <a href="http://maps.google.de/maps?hl=de&amp;saddr=Hauptstr.%2057%2044789%20Bochum&amp;daddr={$link_target_street}%20{$link_target_postalcode}%20{$link_target_city}" target="{$target}">
        <xslt:value-of select="$linktext"/>
    </a>
</xslt:template>
```

Note that there are [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template).

Further, XSLT has no built-in function to do URL-encoding. However, that is what you need to do when you want to place arbitrary values into a URL.

There are a [few methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425516/xslt-version-1-url-encoding) [to make a URL-encoding](http://www.jonmiles.co.uk/2009/02/url-encoding-with-xslt/) [function available to XSLT](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N3353.html#d4570e157), it depends on your XSLT processor [which one would work for you](http://www.google.de/search?q=xslt%20url%20encode).