# URL encoding with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, escaping, character, href

I have a problem writing my XSL. I have a link with the following code:

```
<a>
<xsl:attribute name="href">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($myUrl,'&amp;projectNumber=',$projectNumber)"/>
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="title">
  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</xsl:attribute>
LINK
</a>
```

So I need to pass a variable `projectNumber` to the end of `myUrl`. This works just fine and I get `...myUrl...&projectNumber=...projectNumber...` in HTML.

The problem is, that the variable `projectNumber` sometimes has some characters which have to be escaped in the href of my link. I tried using the XSL function `str:escape-uri()` in many different ways, but still no success...

For example if myUrl is `www.example.com/example.aspx?a=b` and projectNumber is `aaaūaaa`
I get href like `www.example.com/example.aspx?a=b&projectNumber=aaaūaaa`, but I need to get `www.example.com/example.aspx?a=b&projectNumber=aaa%C5%ABaaa`. (`%C5%AB` is the way that 'ū' is escaped) Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using XSLT 1.0,
then refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425516/xslt-version-1-url-encoding).

In case of XSLT 2.0, you may use this to solve the issue.

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($myUrl,'&amp;projectNumber=',encode-for-uri($projectNumber))"/>
```

Comment: tried the same code with 'encode-uri' instead of 'encode-for-uri', but it still doesn't work both ways :/

Comment: No, I haven't tried, can you please show me an example how can I pass the projectNumber to embedded JScript and return the escaped projectNumber?