# Percent-encoding using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml in which the value of `<prvNum>` has some special characters.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <prvNum>SPECIAL#1&amp;</prvNum>
</root>
```

Now I want to perform percent-encoding for the value of `<prvNum>`. For example the value should be changed as below after percent encoding:

SPECIAL%231%26

I am trying with the following code snippet, but couldn't achieve the desired percent-encoding:

```
encode-uri(<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(//prvNum)"/>)
```

My complete XSLT is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <Request>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//root" />
      </Request>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Request">
      <requestSpecific>
         <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(//prvNum)" />
      </requestSpecific>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anybody tell me where I am doing the mistake?

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0? If so, you could use the "encode-for-uri" function.

Comment: @TimC , I have used "encode-for-uri", but still the same result. Am I missing anything? And How can we achieve the same uisng XSLT1.0?

Comment: This question may help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425516/xslt-version-1-url-encoding

Comment: Why "encode-for-uri" is not working with XSLT2.0?

Comment: @TimC: I completed your comment to a full answer. I hope that this is OK for you. Otherwise I would make it 'community wiki'.

Comment: That's no problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am just implementing the application of the XPath 2.0 function [`encode-for-uri`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_encode-for-uri.html) suggested by *TimC*. So the XSLT 2.0 should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

   <!-- identity template -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>   

   <xsl:template match="prvNum">
      <prvNum>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
        <xsl:value-of select="encode-for-uri(text())" />
      </prvNum>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Awesome!!..+1 for perfect answer.. Thanks!!

Comment: I have to use only XSLT 1.0 as per my requirement. how to achieve the same using XSLT1.0? I have posted a new question with the XSLT code that I tried with . It would be great if you can provide a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158893/percent-encoding-using-xslt-1-0