# Percent-encoding using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using XSLT 1.0 and I am not supposed to use XSLT 2.0. 
I have the following xml in which the value of `<prvNum>` has some special characters.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <prvNum>SPECIAL#1&amp;</prvNum>
</root>
```

Now I want to perform percent-encoding for the value of `<prvNum>`. For example the value should be changed as below after percent encoding:

```
SPECIAL%231%26
```

I am trying with the following code snippet, but the stylesheet is not compiling.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:custom="http://youdomain.ext/custom" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" version="1.0">
   <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="custom">function uriencode(string) {
 return encodeURIComponent(string);
}</msxsl:script>
   <!-- identity template -->
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="prvNum">
      <prvNum>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
         <xsl:value-of select="custom:uriencode(text())" />
      </prvNum>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anybody help me to fix the issue?

Comment: I suspect you need to bind the `custom:` prefix to a namespace before you can use it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Thanks for the response. I am getting the error `Unable to generate the XML document using the provided XML/XSL input. Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {http://youdomain.ext/custom}uriencode()` after I bound the `custom` prefix. Could you please help me out in figuring out the solution?

Comment: Are you in fact using a MSXSL processor?

Comment: @ michael.hor257k, Honestly I am not sure which processor I am using. We are using java and Spring Integration in our project. How to know which processor I am using?

Comment: The code above will only work in Microsoft's MSXSL: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/533texsx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx See here how to find which processor you have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033?s=1|0.1818#25245033

Comment: @michael.hor257k,  I am using "Apache Software Foundation (Xalan XSLTC)" processor.

Comment: Then look at: https://xalan.apache.org/old/xalan-j/extensions_xsltc.html