# XSLT Decode stored cookie value from %40 to @

Tags: xslt

I have an issue with the following value field:

`value="{normalize-space(/Properties/Data/Result/header_data/login_form/persisted_username)}"`

Works perfectly well but the username that is pulls from a cookie value sometimes returns %40 instead of @ I believe this is because of the way the data is sanitised in the cookie.

Is there a way of decoding that so that the value will correctly show @ instead of %40.

This is in an xslt file. So preferably something xslt based. I have tried `decode(/Properties/Data/Result/header_data/login_form/persisted_username)` but this broke the page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which XSLT processor will you be using?

Comment: How would I find out, I tried 

<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>

But no dice

Comment: there is this in the file `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`

Comment: What exactly does "no dice" mean? You should get a result - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033. What you write in your stylesheet has no relevance here.

Comment: Apolgies should have been more specific, when I put those into the main file the xslt ceases to function and all I get is raw xml output. As this is a client site I can't share the whole file I am afraid.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you then. Perhaps you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3518109